# extend div beyond bootstraps container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set up in wordpress using bootstrap what follows:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div id="NEEDS TO BE FULL WIDTH>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like the background of the "NEEDS TO BE FULL WIDTH" div be full browser width but not sure how. If I make it more the 100% width it makes a horizontal scroll. Any ideas?

Comment: It's safer to close the container, then have your div not inside of it.  You can use positioning to move it to the edge of the screen but it's a hacky way and may lead to problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple `.container` elements inside your html. If you change the `.container` into a `container-fluid` the content of the container will take up 100%

If you only want the background to be full width, but you want the content to be constrained by the `.container` (at most about 1140 pixels wide) then surround the `.container` with another `<div>` and put the `background-image` on that element.